# Auto-Detect Application "Type"

Tags: delphi

I build four different "types" of applications with my framework:

1) Windows Services
2) Normal Applications
3) Service Applications (a normal application with the functionality of a Windows Service but with a local GUI console and an ability to auto-upgrade)
4) Remote GUI Consoles

Now I can detect, through code, if the application is a Windows Service. But currently to detect between the others I use DEFINES that need to be added to the project file. I would like find an alternate way that does not rely on DEFINES if possible. My initial thoughts are to use the Comments field of the project's version info.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** I am after a general technique that works regardless of how I "type" my applications. At the moment I use DEFINES from the project configuration, which works, but makes the code slightly messier than using "if" code switches, and because it is stored in the .dproj file, can be hidden from view.

**Solution:** From David's suggestion I initially used the conditional defines (and any other information such as whether the application was running as a Windows Service) to map all applications to one of the 4 application types, stored in a globally accessible object. Unless linking files that made no sense to include with a particular application type, I replaced almost all of my conditional compilation flags with code, which significantly improved the readability of the code. There are a few other "tweaks" I implemented, but that was the basic implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending how you are using the `Application` global variable  you can detect if you application is a Service, a VCL or a console App checking the type of this global variable. for consoles app you can use the [`System.IsConsole`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.IsConsole) variable.

```
function ApplicationIsService(Component:TComponent):Boolean;
begin
   Result:=Component.ClassName='TServiceApplication';
end;

function ApplicationIsVcl(Component:TComponent):Boolean;
begin
   Result:=Component.ClassName='TApplication';
end;
```

and you can use like this

```
if ApplicationIsVcl(Application) then
//do something
else
if ApplicationIsService(Application) then
//do something else
else
if IsConsole then
//do another thing
```

Comment: I have the service covered with similar code. The other three applications are all standard VCL applications, so this will not differentiate between these application "types" (the "types" being my logical construct).

Comment: @Misha: well, what are their defining properties? What sets them apart from each other?

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED: There are no defining properties - that is the quandary I have. For example, I can compile exactly the same code for two different projects, one a Windows service and one a VCL application, and apart from the project file and the inclusion of a main form for the VCL application, there is nothing in the code to tell them apart. The remote consoles actually embed the main forms of "service-like" applications within its main form, so even the inclusion of these units does not necessarily imply a particular application "type".

Comment: This solution has the unfortunate downside of evaluating the type of application at run time: every "branch" of the if statement gets compiled into the final EXE. Using conditional defines the "if" statements are evaluated at compile-time, so the not-required branches aren't even linked in.

Comment: @Cosmin: true, but there are actually only a few extra/different lines of code, so the difference is negligible. However, these few lines of code are significant in context.

Comment: See [When is System.IsConsole true in Delphi?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011768/when-is-system-isconsole-true-in-delphi), IsConsole is not very useful

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like each project has a single app type so it seems logical to differentiate in either the .dpr file or the .dproj files.

- Call a function to set a private global variable from the .dpr file.
- Or use a conditional defined in the .dproj as you do now.

If it was me I'd stick to a conditional but use the trick of converting it into a Delphi enum with a shared helper method to make it read better.

Comment: Yes, each project has a single app type. I don't want to modify the .dpr file unless I have to because it can be auto-generated and changes can get lost. Converting a conditional to an enum sounds like a good idea for code clarity - thanks.

Comment: +1 for "conditional", that's what I use. With conditional defines one has lots of control, can conditionally add units to the "uses" clauses, or replace full blocks of code with "stubs". And the greatest advantage, they're evaluated at compile time, not at run-time. Functionality that's used in a Forms application will not even get compiled in the Console application.

Comment: @Cosmin: if the differences were large then I would say yes. However, these are all VCL applications (except for the Windows Service) and the only the corresponding GUI units are included with the correct application "type". So for about 10-20 different lines conditional compilation will not make much difference to the amount of code linked in. They are significant lines of code, though.

Comment: @Misha, 1 line of code is enough to require a `uses` clause that in turn brings in 10k lines of code. Besides, conditional compilation allows for other things as well: Let's say you've got unit "U" that contains code that shouldn't be in the "Service" version of the app. Knowing that your "Service" version defines "SERVICE_VER", you can do a conditional `{$IFDEF SERVICE_VER}{$MESSAGE Fatal 'Error'}` in that unit, making sure you don't accidentally link it in. Conditionals also scale much better and I'm pretty sure you can't escape them in the long run anyway. Hence my vote for David's variant.

Comment: @Cosmin: I agree, and I use them extensively to hook in (or not) some licensed third-party libraries. In this case, if I can determine the app type at run-time (which I am still looking at), the minimal amount of different code would justify NOT using conditionals. Like all things practical, there is a trade-off, and the ability to not have to set any conditionals would outweigh any additional linked code.

Comment: How are you going to avoid doing it one of the two ways I outline?  In a comment to the other answer you state "There are no defining properties".