# When is System.IsConsole true in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, console

According to System.pas, it is documented as `True if compiled as console app`. In System.pas, there is also an assignment

```
{$IFDEF LINUX}
  IsConsole := True;
...
```

I have a strange problem where an app is launched from a Delphi app, using ShellExecute, and then it runs into this code, raising the (unexpected) exception

```
  if System.IsConsole then
    raise Exception.Create(Msg)
```

The application is not compiled with `Project/Options/Linking/Generate console application`. What else could set IsConsole to true?

---

Note that in **Delphi XE2**, OSX applications can not use this variable as it is always true. See [QC Entry 98956](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=98956) and [Why Does My OSX FireMonkey App Think It Is a Console App ?](http://www.deltics.co.nz/blog/?p=791)

Comment: `Project/Options/Linking/Generate console application` and `{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}` are two separate things.

Comment: Your code could be setting it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it: the executable has been created using dcc32.exe and the dpr / cfg file, the cfg contains a line

```
-cc
```

which creates a console application.

The Delphi 2009 Enterprise IDE does not show this setting in the `Project/Options/Linking/Generate console application` dialog. The application was ported from an older Delphi version and maybe something went wrong over the years.

Comment: This exact thing happened to me once, but that was years ago.  There are lots of reasons not to invoke dcc32.exe directly from an msbuild capable version of Delphi, but this just might be the MOST OBSCURE one.

Comment: @Warren it is easy to solve with dcc32 - copy all source files to a fresh target directory, but without the cgf, then invoke the compiler with the correct settings from the script file. I see no advantages of migrating to msbuild in our automated build process, msbuild requires some obscure [preparation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821112/how-does-msbuild-find-the-delphi-search-path) to work on a build server - but maybe this could be community wiki ;)

Comment: If you use post-build steps and do a command line dcc32 compile, the post-build steps don't get done, right?

Comment: @Warren working for years with scripting tools like Apache Ant and Apache Maven we had all build steps automized long before msbuild support was introduced - a case of NCARS